# AJAX - Set-Cookie not working for same domain but different path

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, cookies, cross-domain

The browser doesn't allow me to do something like this:

1) Load `http://localhost:8080/myapp/page1`
-> This sets JSESSIONID cookie with **path=/myapp** and domain=localhost

2) Through an AJAX request I call GET `http://localhost:3000/login?user=xxx`
-> In the response, both in Chrome & Firebug, I see: Set-Cookie: **connect.sid**=XXXXXXYYYYYY **Path=/** domain=localhost

I was expecting that when I performed another ajax call, for instance `http://localhost:3000/anotherCall` (still staying in `http://localhost:8080/myapp/page1`), the browser would send the Cookie **connect.sid** in the headers. However, it doesn't!!

Any idea why? Both cookies belong to the same domain, the only difference is the path so there shouldn't be any cross domain issues.

Additionaly I have tried setting this headers in the NodeJs response. Same result:

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Cookie, Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
res.header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Set-Cookie, X-Powered-By');
```

Checking the Cookies info from Firebug and Chrome dev tools it seems as if the broweser weren't storing the connect.sid cookie at all. I wonder if it's assuming that the domains are different (one is localhost:8080 and the other localhost:3000...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case someone has the same problem. I finally got it to work:

1. Adding additionally the header

   `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');`
2. Setting `xhrFields` in the $.ajax call:

   xhrFields: {
       withCredentials: true
   }

Now the cookie is added in the browser and sent in subsequent requests.